# Array sorting backwards?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Okay so I have this function that takes an array and sorts it by using swap sort(?) however when I enter the numbers it sorts it from largest to smallest instead of smallest to largest.

I went through and did this to see what happens each step of the way however it all seems correct to me.

```
iterator = &first element
temp = smallest number
tempstore = &smallest number
val tempstore = val first element
val first element = val temp
```

If i change it so that

```
if(array[i] < *iterator)
```

becomes:

```
 if(array[i] > *iterator)
```

it works perfectly but I don't understand this as now it is testing to see if the number is larger and I want smaller.

I know I should probably be using a vector but I am still a newbie and I am yet to learn them. Thanks for any help.

```
int *sort(int *array, int size)
{
    int temp, *iterator, *tempStore;
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        iterator = &array[j];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] < *iterator)
            {
                temp = array[i];
                tempStore = &array[i];
                *tempStore = *iterator;
                *iterator = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::sort( array, array + size );`

Comment: `i` needs to start iterating from `j + 1`. Otherwise you are interfering with the already sorted part of the array.

Comment: *"I know I should probably be using a vector but I am still a newbie and I am yet to learn them."* Learn about `std::vector` as soon as you can and leave pointers behind, at least for a while.

Comment: Thank you. That j + 1 worked fine and I believe that vectors are up next in the book I am reading. In the std::sort what does the "array + size" mean?

Comment: @user2999132: `array + size == &array[size]`. It's pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm compares the first element of the array with all the subsequent, so when you use:

```
 if(array[i] > *iterator)
```

you swap the first element with the `i`th element every time the `i`th element is greater than the first. So at the end of the first pass you have the greatest element in the first position. if you use the `<` operator, you get the smallest in front.

Then the second pass should compare the second element of the array with all the subsequent and so on, that's why `i` needs to start iterating from `j + 1`.

As you saw it is not straightforward to read and understand the code, moreover the algorithm itself is very poor (it looks like a [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) with some extra swaps). You do not necessarily need to use a `std::vector` but you really should learn the standard library.

This is the C++11 way to do it:

```
#include <algorithm> //for std::sort
#include <iterator> //for std::begin/end
#include <functional> //for std::greater

int v[1000];
... fill v somehow ...
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::greater<int>());
```

Compact, clear and extremely fast.